# Обрезание адреса сайта

Tags: веб-программирование, домен

У меня есть сайт, например: www.site.ru. Если зайти в раздел "полезное", адрес будет выглядеть так: www.site.ru/poleznoe.
**Вопрос:** как не выводить в адресную строку браузера это окончание "/poleznoe", а при нажатии на адресную строку - выводить?
*Я думаю, что нужно изменить файл .htaccess.*

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь если пользоватся post запросами то url не будет менятся. а при get запросах меняется (<form action="post" / form action="get">).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант адрес странички (poleznoe) передавать как GET параметр:
*www.site.ru/index.php?page=poleznoe*
Большинство(!) браузеров скрывают GET параметры так, как вам хочется :)
**P.S.** останется решить только то, как будет выглядеть ваша главная страничка (*index.php* или как-то по-другому).
**P.P.S** Если будете использовать *index.php* то указывать его не обязательно, т.е.:
*www.site.ru/**index.php**?page=poleznoe*
*www.site.ru/?page=poleznoe*
одно и тоже

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую!

Comment: В этом случае, не забывайте про безопасность.
Чтобы не было так, что файл просто подключается по пути, данному в GET параметре. Иначе беда)

Answer (score 5):

> Обрезание адреса сайта

*таки в синагоге выходной*

Нет, для этого вам нужно написать браузер, который бы поддерживал такую возможность, а потом сделать его самым популярным и заставить google, mozilla и opera вшить в браузеры ваш API.

**По существу** - так сделать нельзя. Политика браузера, если хотите (угроза фишинга)

Comment: :) Понял. Спасибо.

Comment: Хотя вот пришла мысль (если ооочень хочется) поизвращаться с history API. Грубо говоря, вешать на body (или какой-то блок, отстоящий от верха на какое-то расстояние) события mouseover и mouseout, в котором обновлять адресную строку. что-то типа "мышь на блоке - показываем site.ru, мышь вышла из блока - показываем site.ru/poleznoe". Это не совсем "клик на адресную строку", но это единственное, что я могу вам предложить) Имейте в виду, что это хак и бредовая штука, но мало ли, что вы там задумали...

Comment: Да ничего я не задумывал :) Просто меня заинтересовал данный вопрос и метод его решения.